# Adjusting Logistic Regression Coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic

I am wondering whether there is ever justification in adjusting your logistic regression coefficients. For example, I have a logistic regression model that predicts that 4% of farmers will go out of business in the next year based on observed covariates at time 0, yet I have another model that is forward looking using macroeconomic data, and I have reason to believe that 5% (or 3%, etc...) of farmers will go out of business in the next year (based on the same sample of farmers).

I am going to make the assumption that the second model will be more precise on an aggregate basis (I don't make that prior assertion, just hypothetically). In order to get the most accurate individual-level probabilities (based on AMSE or MSE for instance) while achieving my desired sample level probability, I want to adjust the coefficients until my desired level is achieved. Can anyone help with a best method to go about doing this, or if I am creating too much bias in doing so?

I don't think adjusting just the intercept will work because the change will be uniform in the logit to all farmers (But maybe?).

Comment: Bayes  - but fiddling the prior to obtain a desired level of posterior precision sounds dangerous